# Is it insecure to send a password in a `curl` command?

Tags: macos, curl

Here’s an example request we can make to the GitHub API:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/authorizations' --user "USERNAME"
```

This will prompt for the account password, to continue:

```
Enter host password for user 'USERNAME':
```

If we don’t want to get the prompt, we can provide the password at the same time as the username:

```
curl 'https://api.github.com/authorizations' --user "USERNAME:PASSWORD"
```

But is this method less secure? Does `curl` send all the data at once, or does it first setup a secure connection, and only then send the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Regarding the connection there's no difference: the TLS is negotiated first and the HTTP request is secured by the TLS.

Locally this might be less secure, because:

- The password gets saved to the command history (`~/.bash_history`) as a part of the command. *Note:* This can be avoided by adding a space in front of the command before running it (provided you have the setting `ignorespace` in variable [`HISTCONTROL`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#index-HISTCONTROL)).
- On a shared system, it will usually be visible to others in `ps`, `top` and such, or by reading `/proc/$pid/cmdline`, for as long as the command is running.
- Storing the password unsecured in a script might pose a security risk, depending on where the script itself is stored.

Comment: Thank you. I’m not sending it directly through the shell. I’m asking for it via `read` in a script.

Comment: Then you must keep the script in a safe place. I'd recommend `700` permissions.

Comment: to solve the issue with `.bash_history` you could just prepend a space in front of your command. This way it doesn't get saved to history. (further info over here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115917/why-is-bash-not-storing-commands-that-start-with-spaces )

Comment: This doesn't solve the `/proc/${pid}/cmdline` issue (e.g., it showing up in `ps` output). If there are multiple users on a system, this is a great way to accidentally disclose a password.

Comment: @StephenTouset check here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/385339/135943.  Curl password arguments do NOT appear in ps output, except possibly for a minuscule (and hard to demonstrate) time period after the curl command is invoked.  Should not be relied on entirely for security but it’s pretty effective.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 see my comment above.  It is actually usually NOT visible in the places you mention, although there is a tiny race condition window where it may be.

Answer (score 11):

> But is this method less secure?

No, it is not if you use `https`. When you use `HTTPS` your complete transaction will be encrypted. But as @Esa mentioned it is insecure locally which you can avoid adding a `space` before your command so that the command will not be in your command history. If you are worried about exposing the command on the other users `ps` than hardening `/proc` would help you with that. Follow the link to enable [hidepid](https://linux-audit.com/linux-system-hardening-adding-hidepid-to-proc/).

> Does `curl` send all the data at once, or does it first setup a secure connection, and only then send the `USERNAME` and `PASSWORD`?

No `curl` doesn't send all the data at once. Like other `SSL/TLS` connection, `curl` will initiate `SSL` handshake before passing any data.

You can inspect how your data is transferred with `tcpdump`, `tshark` or `Wireshark` like following, (after running `tcpdump/tshark`, run the `curl` command)

**TCPDUMP**

```
[root@arif]# tcpdump -i eth0 -n src host 192.168.1.1 and dst host 192.168.1.2 and port 443 -XX
```

Where,

- `-i`: for listening on a specific interface which is in this case `eth0`
- `src host` : Specifying source `ip` address
- `dst host` : Specifying destination `ip` address
- `port`: Specifying port `443` which is the default for `SSL` connection. You can change according to your requirement.
- `XX`: For showing header, packet contents and link level header in HEX and ASCII.

You will start to see `gibberish` contents after a few packets. You also can `grep` your password from the packet with the following command,

```
[root@arif]# tcpdump -li eth0 -n src host 192.168.1.1 and dst host 192.168.1.2 and port 443 -XX | grep 'password'
```

If your password shows up there then your password did not get encrypted before transmission. Otherwise, you are okay.

**TSHARK**

```
[root@arif]# tshark -O tls "ip src 192.168.1.1 and ip dst 192.168.1.2" -x
```

Where,

- `-O`: for mentioning protocol.
- `-x`: for see packet contents.

you can `grep` your password with the above command too.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to protect from local users is to use a ".netrc" file. The `curl` man page should have details on how to use it.